# Size for image asset not changing in Animated Splash Screen

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to create an animated splash screen for an app. I have inserted an image in the splash screen using Image.asset() but when I input any number for height or width, the image does not change at all. It remains quite small but I want it to be bigger.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: AnimatedSplashScreen(
          duration: 4000,
          splash:
          Image.asset("assets/icons/icon.png",
            height: 200),
          nextScreen: Homepage(title: "Travel Nepal",),
          splashTransition: SplashTransition.fadeTransition,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffF99DC8),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Size of Image :
[image]

I have used the "fit: BoxFit.fill" property as well but the image gets distorted or cut off abruptly. Any suggestions on how to implement a change into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you can use the splashIconSize property of the AimatedSplashScreen widget.

https://github.com/clean-code-dev/animated_splash_screen/issues/18

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much, oh my god. I used splashIconSize: 200 and it turned out perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```
AnimatedSplashScreen(
splash: 'assets/images/Splashscreen.png',
splashIconSize: double.infinity,
splashTransition: SplashTransition.fadeTransition,
nextScreen: MainPage())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AnimatedSplashScreen(
        duration: 3500,
        splash: 'assets/images/app_logo.png',
        splashIconSize: double.maxFinite,
        nextScreen: CompanyList(),
        centered: true,
        splashTransition: SplashTransition.rotationTransition,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white),
```